# If value > threshold, assing value 1, if value < threshold, assign value 0

Tags: r

I have an array `vals` that contains values between `0` and `1` and I also have defined a threshold, `th`

```r
vals <-  c(0.0374250747263432, 0.00394217809662223, 0.0719008445739746, 
    0.0930692106485367, 0.0615200139582157)

th <- 0.5
```

How can I create a second vector `vals_bnry` whose elements are values of `0` *or* `1` based on the size of the corresponding elements in the `vals` vector?

Example:
`if vals[1] > 0.5` -> `vals_bnry[1] = 1`

Is there a way to avoid the for loop?

Comment: `as.integer(vals > .05)`

Comment: A code-golf approach is `+(vals>th)`

Answer (score 1):

Use the function `base::ifelse()`, like so:

```r
ifelse(vals > th, 1, 0)
```